# AngularJS controller in different files error

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

My app.js file

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','myApp.controllers']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/products/list', { controller: 'ListCtrl', templateUrl: 
                '/app/views/productlist.html' });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

my productcontroller.js file

```
'use strict';   

var myApp= angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);
myApp.controller('ListCtrl', [function () {
      $scope.name = "xyz";
}]);
```

My MVC4 List.cshtml view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Product List";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<header>
   <h1>Products</h1>
</header>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

And here is the html page which I want to include in my MVC view **productlist.html**

```
<input type ="text" ng-model="name" />
<br />
{{name}}
```

Every thing is running smooth, no error, but it is not including anything to the page.

I know it's very basic question, I just started now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in your controller. Change it like this

```
var myApp= angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);
myApp.controller('ListCtrl', [function ($scope) {
      $scope.name = "xyz";
}]);
```

You weren't injecting `$scope` to your controller.

Comment: Problem is with routing, I was using the MVC routing for that view which is not correct for the angularJS routing with my app.js, that's why nothing was working, so changed my mind to use the html and not to cshtml. thanks for your reply.